Data Model Design Question
I have a design question. Our organization provides equine-assisted therapeutic riding instruction. At the end of every quarter, each rider is evaluated to measure their progress. The rider info is stored in the Participant object. The skills that we measure are in the Skills object. Skills has a Lookup(Participant) field that joins the two.
The evaluation process is as follows. At the end of each quarter, for each rider, a number of skills are evaluated. They are listed in a picklist and the person evaluating selects them one by one and makes the evaluation. Screenshots attached.
Note that Session (which is the quarter being evaluated) and the Year appear in every record and have to be reentered every time a new skill is selected from the picklist. I default the Year to the current year but if the last quarter is evaluated in January this will be incorrect and must be changed.
Ideally, there would be a table in between that has a Lookup(Participant) field and I assume a one-to-many relationship with Skills. That intermediate table would store the Session and the Year which could then be removed from the Skills records. This will make the Screen Layout and reporting much more complicated.
Alternatively, in the current design after the first entry, there is a "Save and New" option. Can that somehow be used to pass the values for these two fields to the next new entry? That would keep the design simple and eliminate the need to enter the Session and Year multiple times.

Any thoughts on this would be welcome. I suspect a flow might be a possibility but that too gets complicated.

The "intermediate" table is your Evaluation entity, and yes, you need that. You're thinking record-triggered flows to transfer values but a screen flow with reactivity is a good option (versus out of the box UI) for this entire process

Thank you but I am not sure that reactive flows will solve my problem. I am just trying to default two fields that are common to all the child records.

Dependent picklists might work.

Thanks but it is going to take a new object between the Participant and the Skills - I just have to learn how to make keep the UI simple.
